# Porque entra en la condición no deseada

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

No entiendo porque cuando en el prompt le escribo pasapalabra, me entra en la condición que hay una alerta que dice "has fallado".
En teoría debería entrar en la condición de (obj.answer === "pasapalabra") pero me entra todo el rato en la de (obj.answer != userAnswer && obj.answer != "pasapalabra").

```js
var questions = [
        { letter: "a", answer: "abducir", status: 0, question: ("CON LA A.") },
        { letter: "b", answer: "bingo", status: 0, question: ("CON LA B.") },
        { letter: "c", answer: "churumbel", status: 0, question: ("CON LA C.") },
    ]
    
    function pasapalabra(myObject) {
    
        function pregunta() {
    
            var acertados = 0;
            var fallados = 0;
    
            myObject.forEach(function(obj){
    
                var userAnswer = prompt(obj.question);
                console.log(userAnswer)
    
                if (obj.answer === userAnswer) {
                    alert("Has acertado!!");
                    obj.status = 2;
                    acertados++;
                } else if (obj.answer != userAnswer && obj.answer != "pasapalabra") {
                    alert("Has fallado!!");
                    obj.status = 0;
                    fallados++;
                } else if (obj.answer === "pasapalabra"){
                    obj.status = 1;
                    console.log("Pasapalabra")
                } else {
                    console.log("Has salido")
                }
            })
    
            console.log("Aciertos: " + acertados)
            console.log("Fallos: " + fallados)   
        }
    
        pregunta();
    }
    
    pasapalabra(questions);
```

Comment: ¿Las comparaciones no debería ser con `userAnswer` en lugar de con `obj.answer`? Creo que es un simple lapsus al escribir las comprobaciones

Comment: Tienes razon! Estaba comparando cosas distintas. Muchas gracias Pablo Lozano!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que deberías de cambiar las comparaciones con `"pasapalabra"`:

`obj.answer != "pasapalabra"` => `userAnswer != "pasapalabra"`

`obj.answer === "pasapalabra"` => `userAnswer === "pasapalabra"`

Otra buena páctica sería asegurarse de que las comparaciones ignoren mayúsculas o minúsculas (ya que el usuario puede introducir mayúsculas, con lo cual ya no te aceptaría la respuesta como válida), tan fácil de hacer como:

`userAnswer != "pasapalabra"`=>`userAnswer.toLowerCase() != "pasapalabra"`

`userAnswer === "pasapalabra"` => `userAnswer.toLowerCase() === "pasapalabra"`

`obj.answer === userAnswer` => `obj.answer === userAnswer.toLowerCase()`

etc...

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: me sirve muchisimo! Veo que estaba comparando cosas dintintas. Mil gracias! enrique manzano gil

Comment: @jaumeserr Si te sirvió, da la pregunta por terminada, dandole al "check" de la respuesta :), así la página sabe que esta pregunta ha sido respondida

Comment: Listo, le he dado al "check" ya que me sirve mucho. @enrique manzano gil

Comment: Me alegro de que así sea :)